# When does a Vec reallocate if no default size is provided?

Tags: rust, vector

Whats the default size of a `Vec::new()` and when does it reallocate if it exceeds the default size? I'm seeing some performance issues when working with vectors (I think this is the main reason) once they grow enough. The vector has `Vec<u8>` values, so, the resultant vector is like the following

```rs
let items: Vec<Vec<u8>> = Vec::new();
```

I'm doing massive insertions just to see if it's capable of handling millions of values, but as soon as it gets to ~30k values, the insertion process tends to double the time, and as time goes by, it will double again.

I want to store some identifiers within the vector in order to later on implement some pagination on the vector for an API, but I think using unbounded vectors is causing this issue, I'm not sure.

Besides the usage of vectors, I'm also using a `HashMap` at the same time to insert the `Vec<u8>` key and some object as value, so `HashMap` can also be the issue.

Comment: What do you mean by "when does it reallocate if it exceeds the default size"?

Comment: Maybe you can show the code you are talking about so we can take a look.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "massive insertions"? Because `.push()` will be amortized O(1), but if you `.insert()` not at the end then it has to shift elements and can be O(n) cost.

Comment: @kmdreko the thing is, its code based on substrate, but to give you the way im doing the 'insertions' (actually push) is, I'm creating batches of transactions, and because a blockchain executes everything in sequence, it is like doing a for loop with 1k insertions/6s (it's not a big number if you compare with other techs, but for blockchain it is kinda big). Anyways, I think Chayim provided a really good answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> whats the default size of a `Vec::new()`

[Zero](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.new):

> The vector will not allocate until elements are pushed onto it.

> when does it reallocate if it exceeds the default size

It is unspecified, but [currently the growth rate is 2x the previous capacity](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.61.0/src/alloc/raw_vec.rs.html#394) ([starting from 1/4/8 depending on the element size](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.reserve_exact)). That is, the vector doubles its size every time you push a new element and it has no capacity left. This is usually a good growth rate, but if you insert a lot of elements you can indeed end with very bad performance and memory usage because you may allocate roughly double the memory you need and the last reallocations can require very large copies.

Note that not every time you grow one-by-one - for example, if you `extend()` by an iterator (or `collect()` an iterator), the iterator may know its exact size and allocate only once.

If you know the required number of elements ahead of time, you can call [`with_capacity()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.with_capacity) or [`reserve_exact()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.reserve_exact) to ensure the vector will allocate only once.

Answer (score 3):

You can check how much space is available in a `Vec` with [`capacity`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.capacity). The `Vec` reallocates when you exceed its capacity (which by default is 0).

Note however that when `Vec` does reallocate, it allocates some extra capacity so that it won't need to reallocate on each insertion. It is in fact guaranteed that pushing to a `Vec` will always take amortized constant time. See [Capacity and reallocation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#capacity-and-reallocation) for details.